# CakePHP select many to many (HABTM) records

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

after create a many to many (HABTM) relationship between 2 classes (as code bellow) I was expecting to see results including the related records but for some reason this is not happening.

**Models**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class NewsCategory extends AppModel{
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('News');
}

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class News extends AppModel{
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('NewsCategory');
}
```

I created a table called "news_news_categories" with both tables id.

**Controller**

```
this->data = $this->News->find('first', array('conditions' => array('News.id' => $id)));
```

The result from code above doesn't include the related NewsCategory records.

After spend hours trying to make this happen, I couldn't get this done.

What I'm missing here?

Thank you all in advance!

---

**Update**

When I dump the SQL code used by CakePHP using

```
echo $this->element('sql_dump');
```

the results didn't show any query (or joining) for this relationship. CakePHP is simply ignoring the $hasAndBelongsToMany config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Basically I did the following steps:

1. Created a new php file to represent the relationship model (for some reason I had understood that CakePHP would do it automagic behind the scenes)

   ```
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
   class NewsNewsCategory extends AppModel{
     var $belongsTo = array('News', 'NewsCategory');
   }
   ```
2. Changed my query code to bellow:

   ```
   this->data = $this->News->find('first', array('conditions' => array('News.id' => $id)), 'contain' => array('NewsCategory'));
   ```
3. Finally I was expecting to get the results inside the same array like:

   ```
   $this->data['News']['NewsCategories'] //or anything like that
   ```

But I discovered the related NewsCategory records was available on another var:

```
$this->data['NewsCategory']
```

(and not nested in the News result array, as I first supposed)

Thank you all. I hope this helps other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold follow coding conventions by cakephp or your code will simply `Not work as expected` or you will have to use Dirty tricks like `$useTable = etc`.

Your problem is your table name for HABTM should be

1.All lower case letters

2.It should have both table names(in plural).

3.Plural tables names(i.e. Words) should be in alphabetical order/

4.There should be underscore in between your table names.

As per rules your table name should be `news_news_categories` .

Also ensure in your table `news_news_categories` you have Foreign keys like `news_id` and `news_category_id`. And ensure you dont have any Primary key (like id) in `news_news_categories` table as both fields combinely work as primary key.

Comment: sorry, was a typing mistake (fixed it on my original question). the table was already name lowercased as you mentioned.
Why the join table (news_news_categories) can't have an id column? Im asking because it has the id column and Im not having any problems creating the records... only when selecting its not working

Comment: BTW, I just got this working and didn't need to remove id column from the relationship table. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I think here is problem for CakePHP Conventions. So you just put the use table name in your models.
like as

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class NewsCategory extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = 'news_categories'; 
    // This model uses a database table 'news_categories'
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('News');
}

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class News extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = 'news'; // This model uses a database table 'news'
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('NewsCategory');
}
```

Also Read CakePHP [Books](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)

Comment: Why would I name my NewsCategory model table as "news_news_categories"??

Comment: "news_news_categories" should be "news_categories", was a type mistake.

Comment: actually this was not the problem, since all tables followed the conventions. thanks for your support anyway